# Android Error - Market requires the minSdkVersion to be set to a positive 32-bit integer in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm trying to upload an App onto the Market Place and i'm getting the following error "Market requires the minSdkVersion to be set to a positive 32-bit integer in AndroidManifest.xml." after i export the signed Application Package using Eclipse. My Manifest File looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.recipes"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk minSdkVersion="7" 
                android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Anyone know why i'm getting this error?

Thanks,

O

Comment: Got it sorted i had <uses-sdk minSdkVersion="7"></uses-sdk> instead of <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"></uses-sdk>